# Running ode, dopri5 method, error: unsupported operand type 'ode'

Tags: python, ode

I'm a beginning programmer and I would like to integrate a function using ode 'dopri5', but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. The reference wasn't much help and I'm having an error that I don't recognize. So, originally I was using odeint, and it was working fine. Here is that chunk of code:

```
Itmp = odeint(te.rhs, Itmp, [xLim[i], xLim[i+1]], mxstep=10000,
                          atol=1e-11, rtol=1e-11, args=(f,))[1]
```

And my attempt to integrate using dopri5 is this:

```
Itmp = ode(te.rhs).set_integrator('dopri5', max_step=10000,atol=1e-11, rtol=1e-11)
```

The error I get is saying that Itmp is type 'ode' while I need it to be a float, like the odeint gives me.

Here is the specific error, (I try to subtract Itmp from a float):

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ode' and 'float'
```

And when I use the python debugger and try to print out Itmp, it gives me

```
<scipy.integrate._ode.ode object at 0x10d6ab410>
```

And after I continue it stops with the above error. I'm guessing I don't have the ode command written out correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post an [mcve]? As it stands, it is hard to tell where your problems originate. The only thing that comes to mind is that you use the same variable name for your initial conditions and integrator object (`Itmp`), which is horribly bad practice and likely to lead to errors.

Comment: Did you account for the different argument orders of the ODE functions? While `odeint` requires `odefunc(state, time)`, `ode` uses `odefunc(time, state)`.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the constructor of the `ode` class is an instance object of type `ode`. At this point, no integration has taken place. For that you need to call the step functions of the integrator. After the step, the new state is in the `y` field of the `ode` object.

Consult the documentation of the `ode` class for further details.

You should have noted that you did not pass neither the initial conditions nor the end of the integration interval to the integrator.